# Not able to display piemenu as required after first time clicking the button in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wheelnav.js

I'm making a pie-menu using wheel-nav.I got the code from http://pmg.softwaretailoring.net/.I'm displaying the menu on button-click but when i click the button again many sectors of the pie-menu disappear and the texts too.
I tried finding out the solution but faild so i decided to reload the piemenu everytime on button click but the same thing happens,first it is displayed as it should be but again on button click it behaves abnormally.

Here is the image that will make my question clear.

First time when i click the button
[image]

After first time
 [image]

Here is the code i'm using to create the pie-menu on button click

```
  <script>
//circular menu
var i = 0;

function make() {
    if(i===0)
    {
        i=1;
  console.log("here2");
  var piemenu = new wheelnav('piemenu');
  piemenu.spreaderInTitle = icon.plus;
  piemenu.spreaderOutTitle = icon.cross;
  piemenu.spreaderRadius = piemenu.wheelRadius * 0.13;
  piemenu.clockwise = false;
  piemenu.sliceInitPathFunction = piemenu.slicePathFunction;
  piemenu.initPercent = 0.1;
  piemenu.wheelRadius = piemenu.wheelRadius * 0.83;
  piemenu.navItemsContinuous = true;
  piemenu.sliceAngle = 25.714285714285715;
  piemenu.createWheel();
  piemenu.setTooltips(['help', 'friend request', 'create', 'Games', 'Security settings', 'profile', 'signout']);
  }
  else
  {
      console.log('here3');
      $('#piemenu').load(document.URL +  ' #piemenu');
      i=0;

  }

}
```

And the html code:

```
    <div id='piemenu' data-wheelnav data-wheelnav-slicepath='PieSlice' data-wheelnav-spreader data-wheelnav-spreaderpath='PieSpreader' data-wheelnav-marker data-wheelnav-markerpath='PieLineMarker' data-wheelnav-rotateoff data-wheelnav-navangle='167.14285714285714'
data-wheelnav-cssmode data-wheelnav-init>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemicon='?' onmouseup='alert("Place your logic here.");'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemicon='slideshare' onmouseup='requests();'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemicon='pen' onmouseup='create();'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemicon='arrowright' onmouseup='alert("Place your logic here.");'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemicon='gear' onmouseup='settings();'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemicon='edit' onmouseup='profile();'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemicon='disconnect' onmouseup='alert("Place your logic here.");'></div>
</div>
```

And the css code:

```
#piemenu > svg { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#piemenu { height: 400px; width: 400px;right:-50px;top:-119px;position: 
fixed;}
@media (max-width: 400px) { #piemenu { height: 300px; width: 300px; } }
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic] { fill: #497F4C; stroke: none; }
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected] { fill: #497F4C; stroke: none; }
 [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover] { fill: #497F4C;  stroke: none; fill-
 opacity: 0.77; cursor: pointer; }
 [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-basic] { fill: #333; stroke: none; }
 [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-selected] { fill: #fff; stroke: none; }
 [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-hover] { fill: #222; stroke: none; cursor: 
  pointer; }
  [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title] > tspan { font-family: Impact, Charcoal, 
  sans-serif; font-size: 24px; }
  .wheelnav-piemenu-spreader-in,
  .wheelnav-piemenu-spreader-out { fill: #444; stroke: #444; stroke-width: 
   2; cursor: pointer; }
   .wheelnav-piemenu-spreadertitle-in,
   .wheelnav-piemenu-spreadertitle-out { fill: #eee; stroke: #444; cursor: 
     pointer; }
   .wheelnav-piemenu-marker { stroke: #444; stroke-width: 2; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you call createWheel (and all initialization logic in your make function) only once in window.onload

And use `piemenu.spreadWheel();` to show/hide your menu.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.One thing more.I want to close the entire menu along with the spreader button when i click on the spreader button and make it reappear when i click on the user button again.How can i do that

Comment: @softwaretailoring.net...how do i give a different functionality to the spreader button?

Comment: I think you should use a method outside the wheelnav. For example 'display:none'/'display:block' for the holder div. By the way, how can you handle it inside wheelnav when it doesn't appear?

Comment: for different functionality, please check this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sarosoh/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: But all the spread button does is spread wheel or close wheel

Comment: You must create your own custom function to handle show/hide. Here is a [sample](http://jsbin.com/ludoli/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you sooo much

Comment: Just one last thing..everything is happening now like i wanted but,When i make its display none after clicking the button and make it block again then the option i previously clicked the marker stays at that position.how do i make the marker go to the initial position and also set the selected option to the initial option

Comment: wheel.navigateWheel(0); is your friend :) here is a modified [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ludoli/edit?html,js,output)